# Bootstrap4 card not stacking properly in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, layout, bootstrap-4, internet-explorer-11

Hello i need help I'm having a problem in bootstrap4 cards in chrome. it is working properly on ie11 but not in chrome. Please refer to the image below.

IE11 layout
[image: ie11 layout]
chrome layout
[image: chrome layout]

Comment: Please use display: flex;

Comment: Can you share your code in the snippet?

Comment: Without any of code, it is hard to narrow down the problem. And, it seems that the issue is related to the [Bootstrap 4 grid layout](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp), instead of Bootstrap cards. So, can you post enough code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hello, fixed the issue by using col-md-10 on the main div instead of col. Thanks for the answers! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed the issue by using col-md-10 on the main div instead of col. Thanks for the answers! Much appreciated

Comment: Congratulation for fixed the issue. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.